# Listen and answer

Tags: discussion

Listen to Neighbours - 001 - Cut by Sukhjinder Singh #np on #SoundCloud
https://soundcloud.com/sukhjinder-singh-626913618/neighbours-001-cut

This is a link to an audio. I wanna know what the guy yelling at the boy who was dreaming about something..

He says, "hang on... cut that off cut that  off come on...."

I cant understand what he says next...